# Android ImageView Loop

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a set of 4 image views I created in XML, and I am able to do OnTouch on them and they do a visible and invisible. But now I want to do a Invisible and Visible in a sequence,,,, so basically image1 shows, image1 does not show, image 2 shows, image 2 does not show, image 3 shows, image 3 does not show, image 4 shows, image view does not show.... and do that for(int i -0; i < 8; i++).. Where can i do this? and how?, i was told i needed threads.. but i am new to Android and I am not sure how to do it :(

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly you're not looking for them to animate, right? You just want the drawable of the image to change from 1 to n every time you press it?

In that case you won't need threads. Just make an array of your drawables and keep track of which one you're currently pointing to and set the background of your image to the currently indexed one as you click it.  You don't need 4 imageViews in your xml (you need only one)... if I understand what you're actually doing :)

EDIT

Oh... you should have said something about simple simon, I would have immediately understood...

Ok, in that case you will need a an animation thread, but not so much to change the images (though that will also be part of it) but rather to set a timer so that when the computer plays its color patter for the player, it can sit on each color for some time and allow the player to memorize it.

Then you'll want to allow the player to press the colors and have the color "highlight" while they're on the color (and reset when they're off).

I'm not sure what your intention is with your isUser loop but that's definitely wrong (no matter what you're doing).  And while your intention of sleeping is on the right track, you can't sleep in your main thread.

the way to handle this is to start a thread in the touch handler that sleeps for x milliseconds and then does your post sleep task. 
But you don't want to do any of that in a loop... just build an onTouchListener and pass it to each of your four buttons.

Comment: I am just so frustrated with this... i dont know what to do.. I just want to imitate Simon Says with images.. basically the program shows four colors and then the user needs to pick the same... my newb code is above.. I am new to Android but I cant get it to work :((, the ontouch were working.. it was swaping the images but now with the while loop for the system to just go through them is not..

Comment: I will give you as maked as answered anyways... thank you for trying to help me :(

Comment: let me know if my edit helps you at all... it should get you (at least somewhat) unstuck.

Comment: So you mean to create something like public class myView extends View implements OnTouchListener{} 

?

Comment: you have to walk before you can run :)  There are a ton of tutorials on line that show you how to get started with Android.  You need to get your head around what a view is and what an Activity is and how it all fits together.  You don't need to extend View. You should put 4 ImageButtons into your layout xml and get references to them using findViewById() and then add listeners to them. Once you have that working you will add the Thread to show their alternate colors.